# Something before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to execute some code before the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is called?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: Apple does not let us write in the main method :(

Comment: Where did you hear/read that? As long as your code follows apples guidelines you can write whatever you want in `main` (just don't try to use UI elements before the `UIApplication` is started)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement your app delegate `-init` method and it will execute before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Implement your app delegate class `+initialize` method to execute code even earlier (though you cannot access your app delegate instance there - it doesn't exist yet). As has already been said, you can also modify `main()`.

There are a lot of options.

Answer (score 1):

What Joe said, or, if you'd be more specific in what you want to do, we might find a better solution.

Comment: I would like to load some information before the first XIB is shown (set in the NSMainNibFile key of the .plist file)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute code after the XIB is loaded, go to the ViewController of that XIB and do whatever you want in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

For the first time you load the view, or

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

For every time you open the view

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the friends answers/comments, I believe that the uistoryboard's initialviewcontroller's `awakeFromNib` runs before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` too.